# Dropdown Pure Javascript ES6 Issue with Toggle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dropdown

I'm trying to trigger a dropdown with pure javascript that would have the following functionalities:

1. Clicking anyhwere outside the dropdown will close the dropdown
2. The dropdown can be toggled.
3. When clicking a link inside the dropdown, the ability to control
   whether the menu should close or stay open

Now I have an issue. If I try to accomplish 1 (above) I am unable to accomplish 2 (toggle the dropdown) and vice-versa.

Regarding the 3 (above), the fiddle will clearly show you that when clicking a link on the first dropdown, the dropdown doesn't disappear. But when clicking a link from the second dropdown makes the dropdown disappear. How do I control this?

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheEarlyMan/0u6nnakm/

My JS:

```
    class dropdown {

  constructor() {
    this.trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown [data-trigger]');
    this.target = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown [data-dropdown]'); 
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.trigger.length; i++) {
      this.handleClick(this.trigger[i]);
    }
  }

  handleClick(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      el.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) {
      this.handleClose(this.target[i]);
    }
  }

  handleClose(el) {
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
      if (event.target != el && event.target.parentNode != el) {
        if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
          el.classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
    });
  }

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  new dropdown();
}, false)
```

The CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;

  min-width: 10vr;
  padding: 0;
  lost-column: 1/3;
  padding: calc(1vr - 1px);
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 8vr;
  li {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  a {
    padding: 0.5vr 0.5vr;
    &:hover {
      background: #eee;
    }
  }
}

.dropdown-menu, .dropdown-content {
  &.active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding so many listeners? Have you tried using event delegation?

Comment: I don't understand the use for event delegation here, where do you think the event is bubbling? I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: @TheEarlyMan this question has had over 800 views, if you worked out a solution could you paste your own here to help those coming after you. Thx